# Copy system to another computer

Tags: restore, clone, remastersys

Remastersys apparently let you do this? [It's gone now](http://www.remastersys.com/).

I have a development machine, and I'd like to basically clone it, and install it on a laptop, so I don't have to reinstall everything. Is that possible?

I have a bootable usb, that I made persistent, but I only used it to install ubuntu originally. Can I use that to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy to clone a partition with gparted. Boot from your bootable usb, plug in a second usb drive which is bigger than your partition that you are cloning. Start gparted and simply Copy the original and Paste to Unallocated Space on the second usb drive.

Warning: the cloned drive will have the same UUID number as the original partition, so do not boot into Ubuntu on the hard drive with the second usb plugged in. Ubuntu will get confused as to which partition is /

Answer (score 0):

Use either relinux or SystemImager

**Relinux** is a good software to use instead of Remastersys.
 [Here](http://www.howtoforge.com/creating-your-own-distributable-ubuntu-dvd-relinux) is a great tutorial how to use.
Download the latest version from [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/relinux/0.3/0.3.0a2/+download/relinux_0.3.0a2.tar.gz)

**[System Imager](http://system-imaging.blogspot.com.es/)** is a fork of Remastersys.

From System Imager's website:

> System Imager is a tool that images your running system and allows you to make a image of your running machine and install it on another. System Imager is based on the work of Remastersys.

It has been released under the GNU GPLv2 and the source code is available from the developers in [Sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/os4online/files/src/System%20Imager/)